# ArgumentError when accessing pageobject widget

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir, pageobjects, page-object-gem

```
class MainTabsWidget  < PageObject::Elements::UnorderedList
  include  PageObject
  include  PageObject::PageFactory

  link(:first_link, :text => 'First')
  link(:second_link, :text => 'Second')
  link(:third_link, :text => 'Third')
  link(:category_link, :text => 'Category')
  link(:subcat1_link, :text => 'Subcat1')
  link(:subcat2_link, :text => 'Subcat2')

  def goto_tab_item(tab_item)
    items = tab_item.split /\//
    items.each do |item|
      case item
        when 'First'
          first_link
        when 'Second'
          second_link
        when 'Third'
          third_link
        when 'Category'
          category_link
        when 'Subcat1'
          subcat1_link
        when 'Subcat2'
          subcat2_link
      end
    end
  end
end

PageObject.register_widget :main_menu, MainTabsWidget , :ul
```

I have a page called landing page that uses the widget in the following manner....

```
class LandingPage
  include  PageObject
  include  PageObject::PageFactory


  main_menu(:menu_tabs, :id => 'mainMenu')


  def select_menu_item(item)
    menu_tabs_element.go_to_tab_item item
  end
end
```

This actually did work at one point.  If you pass 'First' for  select_menu_item, it will click to the page specified by first_link.  If you specify 'Category/Subcat1' it will click on the category link and then subcat1.

Howerver, something changed.  We are transition from watir-webdriver gem to watir (6.10) gem, and now the code gets the argument exeption

```
'ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)'
```

This occurs when menu_tabs_element gets referenced in any way.  I've run out of ideas to remedy this.

Stack Trace:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/element_locators.rb:10:in `element'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/elements/element.rb:191:in `respond_to_missing?'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object.rb:53:in `respond_to_missing?'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object.rb:70:in `respond_to?'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object.rb:70:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:1047:in `new'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:1047:in `find_watir_element'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/platforms/watir/page_object.rb:1118:in `block in define_widget_singular_accessor'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page-object-2.2.4/lib/page-object/widgets.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in define_accessors'
./lib/pages/menu.rb:13:in `select_menu_item'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page_navigation-0.10/lib/page_navigation.rb:134:in `block in navigate_through_pages'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page_navigation-0.10/lib/page_navigation.rb:129:in `each'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page_navigation-0.10/lib/page_navigation.rb:129:in `navigate_through_pages'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/page_navigation-0.10/lib/page_navigation.rb:67:in `navigate_to'
./spec/refactor/test_spec.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:350:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:350:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:509:in `block in run_owned_hooks_for'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:508:in `each'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:508:in `run_owned_hooks_for'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:460:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:537:in `block in run_before_context_hooks'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:186:in `block in isolate_for_context_hook'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:182:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/memoized_helpers.rb:182:in `isolate_for_context_hook'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:536:in `run_before_context_hooks'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:589:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `map'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1896:in `with_suite_hooks'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block in run_specs'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:79:in `report'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `run_specs'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby22/bin/rspec:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'

1 example, 1 failure, 0 passed

Finished in 6.087 seconds

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the complete stack trace? Can you run with --backtrace

Comment: Added stack trace

Comment: That's part of the po code that I get lost in, but getting that error is a bug, even if there might be a workaround. I'd file a bug with the project and see if cheezy can reproduce & fix it it: https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear to me which change in Watir would cause this issue. It seems more likely a change in Page-Object. At any rate, here are 2 solutions. Note that this was tested with Page-Object v 2.2.4.

**Using Widgets**

As pointed out by [Alexis in Page-Object Issue 263](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object/issues/263), including page object accessor methods in widgets is not as straight forward as one would expect. In the `MainTabsWidget` class, instead of `include PageObject`, you need to do:

```
extend PageObject::Accessors  # to get the accessor methods
attr_reader :platform         # the accessor methods don't work without a platform
```

With this change, your page object should work.

**Using Page Section**

Page-Object has a page section feature that might better suit your needs. It simplifies some of the code (ie address the above issue).

You define a class to represent your main tabs section. Note that you do not need to register the section or have the multi-line setup as with Widgets.

```
class MainTabs
  include PageObject
  include PageObject::PageFactory

  link(:first_link, :text => 'First')
  link(:second_link, :text => 'Second')
  link(:third_link, :text => 'Third')
  link(:category_link, :text => 'Category')
  link(:subcat1_link, :text => 'Subcat1')
  link(:subcat2_link, :text => 'Subcat2')

  def select_menu_item(tab_item)
    items = tab_item.split /\//
    items.each do |item|
      case item
        when 'First'
          first_link
        when 'Second'
          second_link
        when 'Third'
          third_link
        when 'Category'
          category_link
        when 'Subcat1'
          subcat1_link
        when 'Subcat2'
          subcat2_link
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The page object can simply become:

```
class LandingPage
  include PageObject
  include PageObject::PageFactory

  page_section(:menu_tabs, MainTabs, :id => 'mainMenu')
end
```

The clicking of the menu would change to:

```
page.menu_tabs.select_menu_item('First')
```

(or you could continue to define a `#select_menu_item` method in `LandingPage` to avoid downstream changes)